# Regular expression .*? vs .*

Tags: php, regex

I came across a php article about regular expressions which used (.*?) in its syntax. As far I can see it behaves just like (.*)

Is there any advantage of using (.*?) ? I can't really see why someone would use that.

Comment: They behave differently.

Comment: Who was it that said, "in programming, sometimes you face a problem.  Then you use a regular expression to solve that problem.  Now you have 2 problems."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, `.*?` is not. It only makes sense in context though. Given the pattern:

`<br/>(.*?)<br/>` and `<br/>(.*)<br/>`, and the input `<br/>test<br/>test2<br/>`,

`.*` will match `<br/>test<br/>test2<br/>`,

`.*?` will only match `<br/>test<br/>`.

Note: don't ever use regex to parse complex html.

Comment: +1 for nice example, but (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: added a note. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 8):

in most flavours of regex, the `*?` production is a non-greedy repeat. This means that the `.*?` production matches first the empty string, and then if that fails, one character, and so on until the match succeeds.  In contrast, the greedy production `.*` first attempts to match the entire input, and then if that fails, tries one character less.

This concept only applies to regular expression engines that use recursive backtracking to match ambiguous expressions.  In theory, they match exactly the same sentances, but since they try different things first, it's likely that one will be much quicker than the other.

This can also be useful when capture groups (in recursive and NFA style engines equally) are used to extract information from the matching action.  For instance, an expression like

```
"(.*?)"
```

can be used to capture a quoted string.  Since the subgroup is non-greedy, you can be sure that no quotes will be captured, and the subgroup contains only the desired content.

Comment: so usually if you use it as a part of a regular expression (.*?) will be faster than (.*) ?

Comment: @Tiddo: That can't be generalized.  In either case backtracking may occur for some input.

Comment: To clarify, `*` or `*?` should be chosen based on the correct interpretation of the input, not on performance.  If performance is a concern, consider using something other than a recursive backtracking regular expression engine.